# MySQL Select one field, compare, and change another field

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I have two tables "events" and "programs" what I want to do is check programs.program and if it is equal to "General" then change events.template to "General Template"

I don't know if it is helpful to guess at what this would look like but I'll do it anyway:

```
SELECT program, template
FROM programs, events
WHEN programs.program = 'General'
THEN events.template = 'General Template'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the tables related?

Comment: @eggyal programs.eventID and events.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing researching this problem I was able to find an update query that helped me out.

```
UPDATE events
LEFT JOIN programs ON programs.eventID = events.id
SET events.template = programs.program
```

So instead of updating them individually via my above attempt I was able to update them all at once using UPDATE

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `THEN` clause cant be put there. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT program, 
case when programs.program = 'General' then 'General Template' end as template
FROM programs, events
```

Comment: This looks like what I would want but it wasn't updating my events.template field. So I am not sure what was going on. As stated above though, I figured out something that worked for my needs. Thanks.